# Local/Parent databinding won't work with directive isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to achieve local/parent databinding using the `scope: {test:"="}` notation when defining a directive.

However, in the example below, despite the fact that `console.log($scope.$parent);` logs that the parent scope has indeed a property `test` defined, this code throws the exception `Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'testdirective' is non-assignable`.

The exception is no longer thrown if I use `scope: {test:"=?"}`, but then there are no databinding at stake between the parent and the directive `$scope.test`.

TestCtrl is the controller of a view.

What am I doing wrong ?

**app.js**

```
var ng_app = angular.module('my_app',['ngRoute']);

ng_app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/testroute/', {templateUrl: 'partials/test.html', controller:'TestCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/testroute/'});
}]);

ng_app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){$scope.test = 0;});

ng_app.directive('testdirective', function()
{
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {test:"="}, // this complains that the parent.scope has no property 'test'
        controller: function($scope){
            // this logs a scope with adequate 'test' property defined:
            console.log($scope.$parent);                 
            $scope.test = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

**partials/test.html**

```
<testdirective></testdirective>
```

I use angular 1.2.0rc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `scope: {test:"="}` does not define what you want out of the parent scope.  It defines what attribute that is connected to the enclosing scope.

So, you would need to add an attribute named `test` to your declaration:

```
<testdirective test="test"></testdirective>
```

To make it slightly more clear, let's rename the attribute to `myModel`:

```
ng_app.directive('testdirective', function()
{
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {myModel:"="}, 
        link: function($scope){

            $scope.myModel = 1;
        }
    }
});
```

With the declaration:

```
<testdirective myModel="test"></testdirective>
```

Comment: hmm I think what you say is done with {test:"@"}. If I quote the API documentation : @ or @attr - bind a local scope property **to the value of a DOM attribute**. = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding **between a local scope property and the parent scope property** with the name given as the value of the attr attribute.

Comment: @ does not create a two-way binding.  So, if you only want to bind the value into the directive scope, then use @.  Otherwise, if you want to change the value inside the directive and have the value 'bind back out' use =.